# Basic AngularJS NVD3 Directives will not work and no error

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I made a pretty basic one according to [their official setup](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives) , but its not showing any chart at all and no error returned.

I wonder is it because I did not use bower? I am pretty confused at the moment. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks

```
<?php
/**
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/library/nvd3js/1.1.15b/nv.d3.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/d3js/3.4.11/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/nvd3js/1.1.15b/nv.d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/angularjs/directives/nvd3ChartDirectives/0.0.7/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

        function ExampleCtrl($scope){
            $scope.exampleData = [
                {
                    "key": "Series 1",
                    "values": [ [ 1025409600000 , 0] , [ 1028088000000 , -6.3382185140371] , [ 1030766400000 , -5.9507873460847] , [ 1033358400000 , -11.569146943813] , [ 1036040400000 , -5.4767332317425] , [ 1038632400000 , 0.50794682203014] , [ 1041310800000 , -5.5310285460542] , [ 1043989200000 , -5.7838296963382] , [ 1046408400000 , -7.3249341615649] , [ 1049086800000 , -6.7078630712489] , [ 1051675200000 , 0.44227126150934] , [ 1054353600000 , 7.2481659343222] , [ 1056945600000 , 9.2512381306992] , [ 1059624000000 , 11.341210982529] , [ 1062302400000 , 14.734820409020] , [ 1064894400000 , 12.387148007542] , [ 1067576400000 , 18.436471461827] , [ 1070168400000 , 19.830742266977] , [ 1072846800000 , 22.643205829887] , [ 1075525200000 , 26.743156781239] , [ 1078030800000 , 29.597478802228] , [ 1080709200000 , 30.831697585341] , [ 1083297600000 , 28.054068024708] , [ 1085976000000 , 29.294079423832] , [ 1088568000000 , 30.269264061274] , [ 1091246400000 , 24.934526898906] , [ 1093924800000 , 24.265982759406] , [ 1096516800000 , 27.217794897473] , [ 1099195200000 , 30.802601992077] , [ 1101790800000 , 36.331003758254] , [ 1104469200000 , 43.142498700060] , [ 1107147600000 , 40.558263931958] , [ 1109566800000 , 42.543622385800] , [ 1112245200000 , 41.683584710331] , [ 1114833600000 , 36.375367302328] , [ 1117512000000 , 40.719688980730] , [ 1120104000000 , 43.897963036919] , [ 1122782400000 , 49.797033975368] , [ 1125460800000 , 47.085993935989] , [ 1128052800000 , 46.601972859745] , [ 1130734800000 , 41.567784572762] , [ 1133326800000 , 47.296923737245] , [ 1136005200000 , 47.642969612080] , [ 1138683600000 , 50.781515820954] , [ 1141102800000 , 52.600229204305] , [ 1143781200000 , 55.599684490628] , [ 1146369600000 , 57.920388436633] , [ 1149048000000 , 53.503593218971] , [ 1151640000000 , 53.522973979964] , [ 1154318400000 , 49.846822298548] , [ 1156996800000 , 54.721341614650] , [ 1159588800000 , 58.186236223191] , [ 1162270800000 , 63.908065540997] , [ 1164862800000 , 69.767285129367] , [ 1167541200000 , 72.534013373592] , [ 1170219600000 , 77.991819436573] , [ 1172638800000 , 78.143584404990] , [ 1175313600000 , 83.702398665233] , [ 1177905600000 , 91.140859312418] , [ 1180584000000 , 98.590960607028] , [ 1183176000000 , 96.245634754228] , [ 1185854400000 , 92.326364432615] , [ 1188532800000 , 97.068765332230] , [ 1191124800000 , 105.81025556260] , [ 1193803200000 , 114.38348777791] , [ 1196398800000 , 103.59604949810] , [ 1199077200000 , 101.72488429307] , [ 1201755600000 , 89.840147735028] , [ 1204261200000 , 86.963597532664] , [ 1206936000000 , 84.075505208491] , [ 1209528000000 , 93.170105645831] , [ 1212206400000 , 103.62838083121] , [ 1214798400000 , 87.458241365091] , [ 1217476800000 , 85.808374141319] , [ 1220155200000 , 93.158054469193] , [ 1222747200000 , 65.973252382360] , [ 1225425600000 , 44.580686638224] , [ 1228021200000 , 36.418977140128] , [ 1230699600000 , 38.727678144761] , [ 1233378000000 , 36.692674173387] , [ 1235797200000 , 30.033022809480] , [ 1238472000000 , 36.707532162718] , [ 1241064000000 , 52.191457688389] , [ 1243742400000 , 56.357883979735] , [ 1246334400000 , 57.629002180305] , [ 1249012800000 , 66.650985790166] , [ 1251691200000 , 70.839243432186] , [ 1254283200000 , 78.731998491499] , [ 1256961600000 , 72.375528540349] , [ 1259557200000 , 81.738387881630] , [ 1262235600000 , 87.539792394232] , [ 1264914000000 , 84.320762662273] , [ 1267333200000 , 90.621278391889] , [ 1270008000000 , 102.47144881651] , [ 1272600000000 , 102.79320353429] , [ 1275278400000 , 90.529736050479] , [ 1277870400000 , 76.580859994531] , [ 1280548800000 , 86.548979376972] , [ 1283227200000 , 81.879653334089] , [ 1285819200000 , 101.72550015956] , [ 1288497600000 , 107.97964852260] , [ 1291093200000 , 106.16240630785] , [ 1293771600000 , 114.84268599533] , [ 1296450000000 , 121.60793322282] , [ 1298869200000 , 133.41437346605] , [ 1301544000000 , 125.46646042904] , [ 1304136000000 , 129.76784954301] , [ 1306814400000 , 128.15798861044] , [ 1309406400000 , 121.92388706072] , [ 1312084800000 , 116.70036100870] , [ 1314763200000 , 88.367701837033] , [ 1317355200000 , 59.159665765725] , [ 1320033600000 , 79.793568139753] , [ 1322629200000 , 75.903834028417] , [ 1325307600000 , 72.704218209157] , [ 1327986000000 , 84.936990804097] , [ 1330491600000 , 93.388148670744]]
                }];

        }
    </script>

</head><body ng-app="nvd3TestApp">
123
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
        Here
        <nvd3-line-chart 
            data="exampleData"
            showXAxis="true"
            showYAxis="true"
            tooltips="true"
            interactive="true">
        </nvd3-line-chart>
    <!-- </div></div> -->

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

<!-- TEST SECTION -->
<pre>exampleData Model: {{exampleData | json}}</pre>

<!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Same issue over here too..Bumped into your post. Did you get it working anyway?

Comment: @VishwaKumar Nop, I end up gave this up and star learning something else because I want to get familiar with 3ds first at this point to understand this extra layer maybe later on. and the answer could be the one to resolve it for sure.

Comment: I've tried using various angular 1.2 versions, 1.3, doesn't work.

Comment: check out the type of quotations, during the paste you get: ” and you will need: " or any other type of special character can mess up your urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am agree with you, it's still not working after some months (if I follow the basic steps, the guide of quick start on github). I was researching for a while and I have changed some links of the libraries and then I got it.

Therefore, I would definitely say the problem are the links to the libraries

I am putting the most basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">                

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.9/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.13-beta/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/lib/angularjs-nvd3-directives/dist/angularjs-nvd3-directives.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.css"/>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);

            function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.exampleData = [
                    {
                        "key": "Series 1",
                        "values": [[1025409600000, 0], [1028088000000, -6.3382185140371], [1030766400000, -5.9507873460847], [1033358400000, -11.569146943813], [1036040400000, -5.4767332317425], [1038632400000, 0.50794682203014], [1041310800000, -5.5310285460542], [1043989200000, -5.7838296963382], [1046408400000, -7.3249341615649], [1049086800000, -6.7078630712489], [1051675200000, 0.44227126150934], [1054353600000, 7.2481659343222], [1056945600000, 9.2512381306992], [1059624000000, 11.341210982529], [1062302400000, 14.734820409020], [1064894400000, 12.387148007542], [1067576400000, 18.436471461827], [1070168400000, 19.830742266977], [1072846800000, 22.643205829887], [1075525200000, 26.743156781239], [1078030800000, 29.597478802228], [1080709200000, 30.831697585341], [1083297600000, 28.054068024708], [1085976000000, 29.294079423832], [1088568000000, 30.269264061274], [1091246400000, 24.934526898906], [1093924800000, 24.265982759406], [1096516800000, 27.217794897473], [1099195200000, 30.802601992077], [1101790800000, 36.331003758254], [1104469200000, 43.142498700060], [1107147600000, 40.558263931958], [1109566800000, 42.543622385800], [1112245200000, 41.683584710331], [1114833600000, 36.375367302328], [1117512000000, 40.719688980730], [1120104000000, 43.897963036919], [1122782400000, 49.797033975368], [1125460800000, 47.085993935989], [1128052800000, 46.601972859745], [1130734800000, 41.567784572762], [1133326800000, 47.296923737245], [1136005200000, 47.642969612080], [1138683600000, 50.781515820954], [1141102800000, 52.600229204305], [1143781200000, 55.599684490628], [1146369600000, 57.920388436633], [1149048000000, 53.503593218971], [1151640000000, 53.522973979964], [1154318400000, 49.846822298548], [1156996800000, 54.721341614650], [1159588800000, 58.186236223191], [1162270800000, 63.908065540997], [1164862800000, 69.767285129367], [1167541200000, 72.534013373592], [1170219600000, 77.991819436573], [1172638800000, 78.143584404990], [1175313600000, 83.702398665233], [1177905600000, 91.140859312418], [1180584000000, 98.590960607028], [1183176000000, 96.245634754228], [1185854400000, 92.326364432615], [1188532800000, 97.068765332230], [1191124800000, 105.81025556260], [1193803200000, 114.38348777791], [1196398800000, 103.59604949810], [1199077200000, 101.72488429307], [1201755600000, 89.840147735028], [1204261200000, 86.963597532664], [1206936000000, 84.075505208491], [1209528000000, 93.170105645831], [1212206400000, 103.62838083121], [1214798400000, 87.458241365091], [1217476800000, 85.808374141319], [1220155200000, 93.158054469193], [1222747200000, 65.973252382360], [1225425600000, 44.580686638224], [1228021200000, 36.418977140128], [1230699600000, 38.727678144761], [1233378000000, 36.692674173387], [1235797200000, 30.033022809480], [1238472000000, 36.707532162718], [1241064000000, 52.191457688389], [1243742400000, 56.357883979735], [1246334400000, 57.629002180305], [1249012800000, 66.650985790166], [1251691200000, 70.839243432186], [1254283200000, 78.731998491499], [1256961600000, 72.375528540349], [1259557200000, 81.738387881630], [1262235600000, 87.539792394232], [1264914000000, 84.320762662273], [1267333200000, 90.621278391889], [1270008000000, 102.47144881651], [1272600000000, 102.79320353429], [1275278400000, 90.529736050479], [1277870400000, 76.580859994531], [1280548800000, 86.548979376972], [1283227200000, 81.879653334089], [1285819200000, 101.72550015956], [1288497600000, 107.97964852260], [1291093200000, 106.16240630785], [1293771600000, 114.84268599533], [1296450000000, 121.60793322282], [1298869200000, 133.41437346605], [1301544000000, 125.46646042904], [1304136000000, 129.76784954301], [1306814400000, 128.15798861044], [1309406400000, 121.92388706072], [1312084800000, 116.70036100870], [1314763200000, 88.367701837033], [1317355200000, 59.159665765725], [1320033600000, 79.793568139753], [1322629200000, 75.903834028417], [1325307600000, 72.704218209157], [1327986000000, 84.936990804097], [1330491600000, 93.388148670744]]
                    }];

            }</script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app='nvd3TestApp'>
        <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
            <nvd3-line-chart
                data="exampleData"
                showXAxis="true"
                showYAxis="true"
                tooltips="true"
                interactive="true">
            </nvd3-line-chart>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and also link to jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ackuser/298n6do5/#base

Hope this help.

Comment: COOL! Thanks :) hope it will be some help for those interested :)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an `<svg></svg>` element in between your directive tags. give it a height. ( i would've made this a comment if i had more reputation) .

Answer (score -1):

you should try adding an id to the directive

```
<nvd3-line-chart 
        id="exampleId"
        data="exampleData"
        showXAxis="true"
        showYAxis="true"
        tooltips="true"
        interactive="true">
</nvd3-line-chart>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't create properly controller `ExampleCtrl`.

Try to properly create controller:

```
app.controller("ExampleCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.exampleData = {
        ...
    }
}]);
```